# How to integrate settings.yml in a new project symfony?

Tags: symfony, parameters, get, command

I created a new project symfony 6 because I need to migrate an old project silex.

I never worked with symfony. It is a project that uses Console Commands, basically, to work with instances bachups, migrating and restoring. I have a file like this:

```
global:
  db.host: 57
  db.port: ''
  db.user: www
  db.password: www
  db.charset: www
  hostname: host
  trigram: www
  dev: 0
  username.autofill: true
  timeout: 25000
```

I need to use theses informations in all command.
How can I do this properly ?

I saw that I can put this in services.yml -> parameters.
I don't know how I can access this informations after in commande classes.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your parameters in services.yaml.

```
parameters:
    db.host: 57
    db.port: ''
    db.user: www
    db.password: www
    db.charset: www
    hostname: host
    trigram: www
    dev: 0
    username.autofill: true
    timeout: 25000
```

Then in any class you can access the *ParameterBagInterface*.
For example:

```
namespace App\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;

class MyCustomCommand extends Command
{
    protected $params;

    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    public function getDbHost(): int
    {
        $dbHost = $this->params->get('db.host');

        return $dbHost; // 57
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use in config/services.yaml

```
parameters:
    db.host: '%env(DB_HOST)%'
    db.port: '%env(DB_PORT)%'
    ..... etc.
```

In this case the parameters will not give you a connection class, so, you should need to create that like this in config/services.yaml:

```
    App\Connection\PDOWrapper:
        class: App\Connection\PDOWrapper
        arguments:
            - '%db.host%'
            - '%db.port%'
```

src/Connection/PDOWrapper.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Connection;

use PDO;

class PDOWrapper
{
    /** @var PDO */
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct(
        $user,
        $pass,
        $db,
        $connectionName,
        $socketDir = null
    ) {
        $dsn = sprintf(
            'mysql:dbname=%s;%s%s',
            $db,
            $socketDir,
            $connectionName
        );

        $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
        $this->pdo->query(<<<SQL
SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
SQL
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return PDO
     */
    public function getPdo(): PDO
    {
        return $this->pdo;
    }
}
```

this class is a example about how you can create a PDO conection, then you can inject this class to your services throw Dependency Injection, other way is use a doctrine multiple connection if you need it, you can find the documentation in this [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html):

or read the next [link](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-doctrine)